# Coffeescript dropdown value

Tags: forms, coffeescript

I'm trying to show province/state field if country dropdown equals "Canada" or "United States" through Coffeescript.

So far I have (but looks over complex)

```
canada = "Canada"
usa = "United States"
$('#order_shipping_address_attributes_country').change ->
  selected = $('#order_shipping_address_attributes_country :value').text()
  $('#shipping_province').show() if selected is canada
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works:

```
$('#order_shipping_address_attributes_country').change ->
  selected = $('#order_shipping_address_attributes_country option').filter(':selected').text()
  if selected is "Canada" or selected is "United States"
    $('#shipping_province').show()
  else
    $('#shipping_province').hide()
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do

```
selected = $('#order_shipping_address_attributes_country option:selected').text()
```

However, according to http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/, things will perform better with

```
selected = $('#order_shipping_address_attributes_country option')
           .filter(':selected').text()
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the recommended way as per jQuery. I ended up using some of it